# Wildfly command line deploy failure

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly

I am able to run most of these tutorials in Eclipse provided in the Wildfly quickstart here:

https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/

However, I am running into problem when I use command line to do the deployment. For the most basic HelloWorld tutorial, I received this message:

```
mvn clean install
```

is successful. However, the deployment fails:

```
mvn clean install wildfly:deploy
```

Error messages:

ackaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [wildfly-helloworld] in [/home/abigail/study/quickstart/helloworld/target/wildfly-helloworld]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/abigail/study/quickstart/helloworld/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [2 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/abigail/study/quickstart/helloworld/target/wildfly-helloworld.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) < package @ wildfly-helloworld <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ wildfly-helloworld ---
Dec 19, 2015 11:42:10 PM org.xnio.Xnio 
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.2.Final
Dec 19, 2015 11:42:10 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio 
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.2.Final
Dec 19, 2015 11:42:10 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl 
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.3.Final
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.836 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-19T23:42:15-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/162M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project wildfly-helloworld: Could not execute goal deploy on /home/abigail/study/quickstart/helloworld/target/wildfly-helloworld.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection timed out
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: what does it mean? "Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection timed out"

Comment: I think you will find that Eclipse was starting WildFly for you. If just using the command line you will need to start up WildFly from the command line first

Comment: It's indeed work! what does wildfly:deploy exactly do? I checked the deployment/ directroy in Wildfly and can't see the wildfly-helloworld.war file. So where is it deployed?

Comment: I have two wildfly servers, wildfly 8 & 9 in different locations. Does it matter which server I will be starting for the mvn wildfly:deploy?

Comment: No it should work with both. The war should be in $WILDFLY_HOME/content/ with some cryptic hash path

Comment: There is no /content folder. These are the directories under $WILDFLY_HOME: appclient/  bin/  copyright.txt  docs/  domain/  jboss-modules.jar  LICENSE.txt  modules/  README.txt  standalone/  welcome-content/

Comment: If I have a HelloWorld project, and a Wildfly server. When running wildfly:deploy in HelloWorld project, how is it deployed into Wildfly directory? Wildfly server could be in any directory, and how does HelloWorld wildfly:deploy find the Wildfly server? I am not clear about how a Maven project relates to a Wildfly server in deployment process.

Comment: It's not supposed to matter how it's deployed. How any Java EE server deploys an application is undefined, so the implementation is free to do what ever it wants.

Comment: WildFly exposes a management interface at http://localhost:9990 (by default). The maven plugin uses this to deploy the application.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if you created a user for the deployment.See [this article](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/articles-jenkins-deploy) where it is further explained .

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know wildfly plugin inside pom.xml should be specified with the created user.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when the other application is usind default 9990 port.
I moved wildfly to the `port 9991` (modifying `standalone.xml` and `host.xml`), admin console started to work, but deploy still was failed.
Then I figured out that `wildfly plugin` uses same 9990 by default.

I handled this by modiying `pom.xml` of my progect, put the other port (the same I was using in standalone) to the configuration of wildfly plugin.

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>

             <configuration>
                <port>9991</port>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
```